# How to decompose a running total?

Tags: sql, excel

I have access to a simple Excel sheet I am trying to get data from using Excel SQL (jdbc-odbc bridge). This information is from a printer system, but the data is sent to me monthly with cumulative information. So, for example, I get this:

[image]

The problem is that what i needed was that month 11 showed me `44600` (82006-37406).

I have found a lot of information on how to do running totals, but nothing on doing the reverse.

Is there a way to do this with standard SQL?

Comment: Can you add new column to excel? There you can just subtract cumulatives to get prints count for single row. If not, then you have to query excel two times, join results by `T1.month = T2.month - 1` (plus year comparisons) and subtract total_prints from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL method is `lag()` (an ANSI standard function available in most databases):

```
select year, month, total_prints,
       (total_prints - lag(total_prints) over (order by year, month)) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I tested it and it works on a standard database. Unfortunetely, the function lag does not work on excel odbc. I am thinking that it might be a lost case.

Comment: @valter.vx - there are few (if any) lost cases in developers world :)